# Enterprise Web Library web.config not currently compatible with Azure?

Tags: azure, web-config, enterprise-web-library

I am trying to use Enterprise Web Library with Windows Azure. It appears that the web.config file for the EWL project works fine locally, but when I deploy to Azure the application cannot initialize. After logging in and viewing the site locally on Azure, it appears there are several web.config elements EWL requires that are locked on Azure.  I've had to edit the following in order to have the application initialize on Azure:

- Remove `<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="8388608" />`.
- Remove everything nested inside of the `modules` element.

The application seems to run fine on Azure after removing these parts.

Answer (score 1):

The Web.config elements you removed are important to ensure that EWL works properly: `uploadReadAheadSize` fixes a problem with client certificate authentication, and using `<clear/>` in the `<modules>` section makes the behavior of EWL applications consistent across different servers by keeping the same set of modules in the pipeline regardless of what IIS features are installed on the machine.

There has to be a way to unlock these config sections in an Azure web role. Assuming they are locked in the web role's applicationHost.config file, maybe you can modify this file using a startup script as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10140024/35349.

Comment: I didn't even think of running a startup script. It's unfortunate we (anyone using Azure) have to do this to automate the configuration of Azure deployments. I'm also not very familiar with Powershell, however your suggestion lead me to find this: http://richardprodger.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/azure-iis7-configuration-with-appcmd/.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with Enterprise Library. If William’s suggestions do not help, please check your web.config to see if you’re missing any configuration sections. On your local machine, when you install Enterprise Library, it may modify machine.config to add certain configurations. But they may not exist in the cloud. So please search your local machine.config to see if there’re any Enterprise Library specific sections, and then add them to your web.config.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: This question is about the [Enterprise **Web** Library](http://enterpriseweblibrary.org), a new open source project. It's not about the Enterprise Library from Microsoft.

Comment: I just think the difference is that on my local machine these sections are not locked.